# Is XE Profiler (SSMS 17.3) is available with SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms-2016

I'm checking out newer version of SSMS 17.3 which includes this new feature XE profiler. As XE profiler is working fine for my local instance but when i connect to SQL Azure database using same version of SSMS I don't see the XE profiler anywhere. is this a User rights related issue or this feature is not available with SQL Azure yet.

Answer (score 2):

It is not available for Azure SQL Database yet. It works with SQL Server instances because it uses the live target which is only in the box offering.

The new SQL Operations Studio tool just announced at PASS summit will support viewing XEvents from both cloud and box, but it uses the ring buffer target.

Hope this helps.